# 1-manifold not locally homeomorphic to a 2-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

> Prove that a $1$-manifold ($1$ dimensional manifold) cannot be locally
> homeomorphic to a $2$-manifold.

A $k$-manifold is a topological space $(X,\tau)$ which is Hausdorff, second countable and for all $x\in X$ exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$.

My attempt:

Let $(X,\tau_X)$ be a $1$-manifold, and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ a $2$-manifold. Suppose that $X$ is locally homeomorphic to $Y$. Then there is a function $f\colon X \to Y$ such that
$$ \forall x\in X \ \ \ \exists x\in U_x \in \tau_X \colon \ \ f(U_x)\in \tau_Y \text{ and } f|_{U_x}\colon U_x \to f(U_x) \text{ is a homeomorphism.} $$
Take an arbitrary point $x\in X$. Then for the above $U_x \cong f(U_x)$.
But since $(X,\tau_X)$ is a $1$-manifold, $U_x \cong \mathbb{R}$. And since $(Y,\tau_Y)$ is a $2$-manifold, $f(U_x) \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, which leads to $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, a contradiction.

Can you verify my proof? Can you correct me if I'm wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not every open subset of a $1$-manifold is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, nor is every open subset of a $2$-manifold homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (e.g. every manifold is an open subset of itself, but not necessarily homeomorphic to the Euclidean space of the same dimension).

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you, I see your point now. But now, I have no idea how to do the proof... Can you help me?

Comment: Well, your idea isn't totally off. The point is that not necessarily all, but definitely *some* open subsets of $X,Y$ respectively will be homeomorphic to open subsets of $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2$ respectively and from that you ought to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a $1$-manifold and $B$ be a $2$-manifold. To show that $A$ cannot be locally homeomorphic to $B$, you can show this:

1. if $p \in A$, and if $U$ is a little enough connected neighbourhood of $p$, then $U\setminus \{p\}$ has at least two connected components
2. if $q \in B$, and if $V$ is a connected neighbourhood of $q$, then $V\setminus\{q\}$ is connected

Now, if $f : A \to B$ is a local homeomorphism around $p \in A$, and if $U$ is a connected neighbourhood of $p$, then $f(U)$ is a connected neighbourhood of $f(p)$. Moreover, $U \setminus \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $f(U\setminus \{p\}) = f(U) \setminus\{f(p)\}$ and $U\setminus \{p\}$ has to be connected because of $2.$, which can be easily contradicted thanks to $1.$